# Why not "what on the hell"?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

Many people use the phrase containing the hell, the earth when they get irritated.

> Who *in* the hell are you?

But why only *in* is placed?  We use *Who on earth* is X ?

Why don't we use?

- Who on the hell are you?

Why only use these prepositions used in these sentences?

Comment: They're both metaphoric usages. We use the "container" metaphor for ***hell*** because it's usually thought of as a confined space (often, somewhere *below the surface of the earth*). But without wishing to ally myself with flat-earthers, everyone can see that we live and move about ***on*** (the surface of) the earth, not ***in*** it.

Comment: Does one say "who in the hell"? Most commonly, "who the hell"; perhaps "who in hell". But *who in the hell are you?* seems unidiomatic. Where have you come across this usage?

Comment: @verbose https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=chroB_jTgrE

Comment: Take a look at Google Ngrams: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=who+in+the+hell%2C+who+the+hell%2C+who+in+hell&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwho%20in%20the%20hell%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwho%20the%20hell%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwho%20in%20hell%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cwho%20in%20hell%3B%2Cc0. *who in the hell* barely registers compared to *who the hell*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hell is a region, and for most large-scale places English uses the preposition "in" to describe location.

> I am currently living *in* the United States.
>
> She is sightseeing *in* Hollywood.
>
> He is the tallest man *in* the U.K.

"On" is used for more specific locations that (more or less) you can physically be *on top of*

> She is standing *on* Hollywood Boulevard.
>
> He is *on* the corner of Hollywood and Vine.
>
> I am *on* the observation deck of the Empire State Building.

Of course this idiomatic expression is *metaphorical*, since whoever they are, they didn't actually come from Hell.  It just implies that they look like something that you might find *in* Hell, were you to visit.